# How to avoid unrelated data from postgresql search

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to get the data to contain keyword of both "LED" and "car"

```
select count ( * ) from test_eu where eng_discription ~ '.* led .* AND .* car .*';
```

When I search PostgreSQL with the above code, results include those unrelated data like

so-cal**led** **car**dboard

**car**efully instal**led**

In order to avoid this, I thought both sides of the searching keyword contain space " " solve this problem.

regex of space is

```
\s
```

so I made this code

```
select count ( * ) from test_eu where eng_discription ~ '\sled\s and \scar\s';
```

but still does not work.
How should I modify my code?

Comment: There is no `AND` in regular expressions, so I doubt that your query works like you say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to check for the presence of both `LED` and `car`, anywhere in the description column, you could try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM test_eu
WHERE eng_discription ~* '\yled\y' AND eng_discription ~* '\ycar\y';
```